# why does kdb show 0N 0N 0N 0Ni as websocket response

Tags: websocket, kdb

I've set .z.ws to print the response from the websocket

```
q).z.ws:{neg[.z.w].Q.s value x;}
```

I'm connecting to ws://echo.websocket.org:80 using

```
q)r:(`$":ws://echo.websocket.org:80")"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org:80\r\n\r\n"
```

This websocket just echos back whatever you send it, and have verified this using a browser.

But instead of the console displaying what I send. It just prints 0N, for the same number of characters.e.g.

```
q)neg[r]"test"
0N 0N 0N 0Ni

q)neg[r]"testing"
0N 0N 0N 0N 0N 0N 0Ni
```

Is this something to do with the data being serialised? I've tried using -9! in .z.ws but that didn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successful creation of WebSocket returns a 2-item list- (Handle; HTTP response). To send requests, you need to use 'Handle' instead of full WebSocket object.

Using the full object('r') with input is basically doing the indexing in the 2-item list. That's why you are getting '0N' equal to the length of input on the console as each character indexing returns 0N because of index out of bound. It is not actually sending the request to the server.

Correct way to use it:

```
q) r:(`$":ws://echo.websocket.org:80")"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org:80\r\n\r\n"
q) neg[r 0] "1+1"
q)"2\r\n"
```

More details here: [WebSocket](https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/websockets/#simple-websocket-client-example)

Comment: Thank you very much